# Using the same function for a different chess piece

Tags: python

Recently I was given a programming assignment to mimic the 8 queens problem which I'm sure you are all aware of and was tasked with creating functions for different pieces on the board. For example, placing a queen on the board in such a way that she won't see other queens.

Below you'll find my first function, `queensees`, which basically just highlights the queen's position on the board and identifies whether or not she can see others.

```
def queenSees(pos,size):
  """ Return a list of all squares"In view" of a queen in position pos on a board of size"""
  inView=[]
  #Row and column
  for i in range(size):
      #Column
      setAppend(inView,(i,pos[1]))
      #Row
      setAppend(inView,(pos[0],i))
      #Diagonals
      for r in [-1,1]:
          for c in [-1,1]:
              appendIfInBounds(inView, pointShift(pos,r*i,c*i), size)
  #Take out position of queen so she doesn't see herself...
  inView.remove(pos)
```

Below I've also written a function for the rook piece because it was simply a matter of taking the diagonal search out of the equation.

```
def rooksees(pos,size):
  """ Return a list of all squares"In view" of a rook in position pos on a board of size"""
  inView=[]
  #Row and column
  for i in range(size):
      #Column
      setAppend(inView,(i,pos[1]))
      #Row
      setAppend(inView,(pos[0],i))

              appendIfInBounds(inView, pointShift(pos,r*i,c*i), size)
  #Take out position of queen so he doesn't see himself...
  inView.remove(pos)
```

**How would I modify this to accommodate the knight chess piece?**

Comment: This is not C++..... Looks more like Python or something? Also, would it kill you to capitalise your sentences?

Comment: What does `c++` is doing on your tags`? your code is in python...

Answer (score 0):

A knight moves one of two distances in a cardinal direction, and the other of those two distances in an orthogonal direction. 4 original directions * 2 orthogonal directions each * 2 original distances = 16 possible places. It looks like you already know how to filter out theoretical positions that are actually off the board, so all you need to do is generate those 16 positions in the first place. If you can't see a way to come up with those programaticaly, you could just hard code them like so:

```
positions = [[pos[0]+2,pos[1]+1],[pos[0]+2,pos[1]-1] ... ]
```

But this is very prone to minor typos leading to hard-to-track bugs. A better way might be to just hard code the "adjustments":

```
moves = [(2,1),(2,-1),(-2,1)(-2,-1) ... ]
```

And then use a loop to apply them to the current position:

```
positions = [[pos[0]+d[0],pos[1]+d[1]] for d in moves]
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do for the rook the comment out the diagonal code.

I having trouble implementing a knight see even though I know the coordinates: can anyone tell me how to change the queensees function to display the knight - remember i have commented out the queensees function element i to try and display a knights movements which is not working.

def makeBoard(size):
    board=[]
    for i in range(size):
        board.append([])
        for j in range(size):
            board[-1].append(False)
    return board

def displayBoard(b):
    divider=("+---"*len(b))+"+"
    for row in b:
        print divider
        print "|"+"|".join({True:" X ",False:"   "}[i] for i in row)+"|"
    print divider

def setAppend(s,i):
    """ Add i to s unless i is already in s """
    if not i in s: s.append(i)

def inBoard(p,size):
    """ if point is valid for a board of given size, return True. Else return False """
    if 0<=p[0]

def pointShift(p,r,c):
    """ Return position of cell r,c away from given point p """
    return (p[0]+r,p[1]+c)

def appendIfInBounds(s,p,size):
    """ If point p is within the bounds of a board of given size, append to s unless it's already there """
    if inBoard(p,size):
        setAppend(s,p)

def queenSees(pos,size):
    """ Return a list of all squares "In view" of a queen in position pos on a board of size"""
    inView=[]
    moves = [(-2, -1), (-2, +1), (+2, -1), (+2, +1), (-1, -2), (-1, +2), (+1, -2), (+1, +2)]
    #Row and column
    for i in range(size):

```
    setAppend(inview,(moves[i]))
    #Column
    #setAppend(inView,(i,pos[1]))
    #Row
    #setAppend(inView,(pos[0],i))
    #Diagonals
    #for r in [-1,1]:
        #for c in [-1,1]:
           # appendIfInBounds(inView, pointShift(pos,r*i,c*i), size)
#Take out position of queen so she doesn't see herself...
inView.remove(pos)
return inView
```

def hasQueen(board, points):
    """ Returns True if any of the given points on the given board contain a queen """
    for p in points:
        if board[p[0]][p[1]]:
            return True
    return False

def cloneBoard(b,size):
    """ Make a copy of a board.  Boards are objects (lists are objects) so a=b just makes them refer to the same object..."""
    c=makeBoard(size) #clone
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            c[i][j]=b[i][j]
    return c

def fillBoardRecursion(board,row, size):
    """ Given a board completed to given row, try all possible positions for next row and continue """
    if row==size:
        #Base case
        return board
    else:
        for col in range(size):
            #If we put a queen here, would it "see" another?
            if not hasQueen(board,queenSees((row,col),size)):
                b=cloneBoard(board,size)
                b[row][col]=True
                result= fillBoardRecursion(b,row+1,size)
                if result!=False:
                    return result
        return False #Failed at this point, so return False

b=makeBoard(8)
b=fillBoardRecursion(b,0,8)
displayBoard(b)